# Very much gap between two sections in some chapters

Tags: spacing

I am writing my thesis of \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

In some of the sections of the chapters I find too much of space between the end of one section and the beginning of another . Kindly help me in reducing it[image: See the gap between the previous section and Section 5.1.2]

Comment: Are you using something like `\begin{figure}[H]` close to that point?

Comment: Yes Sir, many like that in my document

Comment: @KiranKU Now you know why we recommend not using `\begin{figure}[H]`. `;-)`

Comment: So do I have to use \begin{figure}[!htb] instead of \begin{figure}[H]?

Comment: You should always use  `\begin{figure}[htbp]`, (or `[htp]`). I only tend to add `!` to the list if I really need to. `\begin{figure}[H]` is just not worth the hassle.

Comment: @KiranKU Please provide a minimal example of your code so that a context is provided.